# Different value inserting @@SPID but is the same connection

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ado

I have a program with classic ASP and a SQL Server 2008 database.

I have many functions that insert different values to the database through a specific function. This is an example of my code

```
Dim Global_connection, global_group
global_group=-1

function connect2server()
    set Global_connection=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    Global_connection.open Connection_string
end function

function data2log(data)
dim sql
    sql = "insert into log(user, module, data, group) values (" & _
            request.form("user") 
            & ", " & constant_module
            & ", 'SPID:' + cast(@@SPID as varchar) + ' -- " & data & "'"
            & ", " & global_group & ")"
    Global_connection.execute(sql)

    if global_group= -1 then
        dim rs
        set rs = Global_connection.execute("select scope_identity() as x")
        global_group = rs.fields("x").value
        rs.close
    end if
end function

function AA()
dim rs, sql
    ''.... blabla code
    data2log("step 1, fine")
    sql = "select...."
    set rs = Global_connection.execute(sql)
    data2log("setp 2, fine")
    rs.close
    ''.... blabla code
end function

function BB()
dim rs, sql
    ''.... blabla code
    data2log("step 3, fine")
    set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    sql = "select...."
    rs.open sql, Global_connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    data2log("step 4, bad")
    rs.close
    set rs = nothing
    ''.... blabla code
    data2log("step 5, fine")
end function

call AA
call BB
```

The values inserted are something like this (select group, data from log):

```
group   data
-1      SPID: 202 -- step 1, fine
1001    SPID: 202 -- step 2, fine
1001    SPID: 202 -- step 3, fine
1001    SPID: 333 -- step 4, bad
1001    SPID: 202 -- step 5, fine
```

Looks the step 4, it have a different ID of connection.

It suppose that **rs.open sql, global_connection** use the same connection, but looks like that open a new connection, because after the **rs.close** it show the original SPID.

Am i wrong? do I need a option in the command rs.open?
if I am wrong, can tell why it is happening.

EDIT:
I have tried changing to

```
set rs.activeConnection = global_connection
rs.open sql, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

but it still fail :(

Comment: Do you actually require the spid, or is this a symptom of something bigger? Because in general, you really shouldn't be caring what specific connection something is happening on, unless you're doing things in a transaction. In particular, storing the spid for any length of time is rather pointless because the values are often recycled -- you can't use them to uniquely identify connections except over brief periods. At best they're good for debugging local phenomena.

Comment: It's a symptom. The problem is actualy with the fucnction SCOPE_IDENTITY that does not return the correct value. I use: sql="SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as x" , set rs = conn.execute (sql), but rs.fields( "x").value is null sometimes.